# Which one is correct, "too many bad luck" or "too much bad luck"? Does the word "luck" need an S (plural) or not?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I'm confused between "too many bad luck" or "too much bad luck"? Does the word "luck" need an S (plural) or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "too much bad luck" and luck goes without an s, both for the same reason.

The reason is that luck as a noun is uncountable, you can't say "Shelby had three lucks yesterday."

Many is used for countable nouns and much for uncountable ones. For example,

- I had too many peanuts to eat (I can count peanuts)
- I had too much  water to drink (I can't count water)
- I had too many bottles of water to drink (I can count bottles)

[Most uncountable nouns are singular](https://www.englishgrammar.org/plural-uncountable-nouns-2/), among them luck. And that's why it goes without an s.